# iOs: how to know whenever a property is accessed

Tags: ios, debugging

I would like to know when a particular property is accessed (set or get). I know that with symbolic breakpoint i can know when a method or function is being called... is it applicable for properties?

@Vladimir & pedro.m:
I tried your answer, but it seems like nothing happens:
[image]

Comment: What happened when u tried?

Comment: I didn't try... i want to know when a property is accessed, not a method or function.

Comment: So did u put a breakpoint on the property?

Comment: You can add breakpoint to a `property` as well. If you need to make any changes when a `property` accessed read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Nothing happens... i really don't know why! I tried putting breakpoints everywhere. Nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, properties are actually just shortcuts that define setter and getter methods for you.

Use symbolic breakpoints to know when they get accessed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as properties are just a syntactic sugar for calling accessor methods you can set symbolic breakpoints to them. If you want to track both setter and getter calls you will need 2 breakpoints: for `-property` and `-setProperty:` methods.